# Get a user's posts ordered by most recent comment on post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql

If I have the following relationship:

```
User
has_many :posts

Post
has_many :comments
belongs_to :user

Comment  
belongs_to :post
```

How do I get a user's posts ordered by the most recent comment on each post?  I'm using Rails with Postgres. Ideally, I'd like to use joins to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier and more efficient in the long run to have your `Post` object's `updated_at` updated when a comment is created. If you don't like the idea of that, you could add a `comment_added_at` attribute and have that updated instead.

This is easy to achieve with the `:touch` option on the association in the child:

```
Comment
belongs_to :post, :touch => true # This will update the Post.updated_at attribute
belongs_to :post, :touch => :comment_added_at # This updates the specified attribute instead
```

Then you can simply order by `:updated_at` or `:comment_added_at` and save a recursive DB query.

If you REALLY want to do it with joins, try this:

```
User.find(1).posts.joins(:comments).order('comments.created_at desc').group(:id)
```

Comment: I like the comment_added_at approach. Using updated_at won't work because edited posts would show up as recently commented on.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: It's worth noting that the `:touch` method will update the post after editing/deleting comments too. If that is undesirable you can use an after_create callback to update the parent instead.

Comment: My scenario was contrived and it's not an issue for me, but worth pointing out for others.  I'm still interested in seeing how to do this with joins. Going to hold off accepting an answer for now.

Comment: You're not grouping the join.

Comment: Sorry - updated my answer. Grouping by the Post's ID is sufficient, since you're ordering by comments.created_at in descending order you will be left with the first result of each matching post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46383/discussion-between-ckarbass-and-jon)

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my app to have it ordered by the most recent post listed on my home page. Maybe it will help you set the order of the most recent comment on the posts.

@posts = Post.select([:id, :title]).order("created_at desc").limit(6)

You may want to do something like the below but not sure if it will quite work for you.

@posts = post.comments.select([:id, :title]).order("created_at desc").limit(6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code as your reference:

```
User.includes(:comments).where("posts.user_id =? ", post_owner_user_id).order("comments.created_at desc")
```

I hope it will give you the desired result.